# JavaScript Delete String starts with/finish with

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some string with the same template:

input:

```
azert,erty,tytr,0.243,jfrd,er,dr,0.85493,ftdre,0.2233
```

output exepected:

```
azert,erty,tytr,jfrd,er,dr,ftdre
```

So I need to delete all `",0." ...`

How can I proceed in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: start with "," then with "0." untill the next "," : for each

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You must have tried *something*!

Comment: @Carlos: You are half way to writing a regex yourself there. Although note that your rule, as you've stated it, wouldn't cover the `0.2233` at the end of your string (there is no next `,`).

Comment: Split on the commas, then filter out the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = 'azert,erty,tytr,0.243,jfrd,er,dr,0.85493,ftdre,0.2233';

var r = s.replace(/(^|,)0[^,]*/g, '');
//=> azert,erty,tytr,jfrd,er,dr,ftdre
```

OR else:

```
var r = str.replace(/(^|,)0[^,]*(,|$)/g, '$1').replace(/,+$/g, "");
//=> azert,erty,tytr,jfrd,er,dr,ftdre
```

Answer (score 1):

> start with "," then with "0." untill the next "," : for each

- Must start with `,` then `0.`
- Must replace with `NULL` up to the next `,`

You can use

```
var str = "azert,erty,tytr,0.243,jfrd,er,dr,0.85493,ftdre,0.2233";
var output = str.replace(/(^|,)0.[^,]+/g, "")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wfhnm6oe/2/

http://regex101.com/r/bS9mY3/1

- `(^|,)` - Match begining of string or comma
- `0.` - Then match 0. literal
- `[^,]+` - Match everything up to a comma
- `/g` - Global flag - all matches (don't return on first match)

Answer (score 0):

```
,\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zX3tG3/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take : http://regex101.com/r/cX6qR7/1

The regex I used is `/,0\.\d+,/g` and a substitution of `,`.

```
var re = /,0\.\d+,/g; 
var str = 'azert,erty,tytr,0.243,jfrd,er,dr,0.85493,ftdre,0.2233';
var subst = ','; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```